Display .odt title property as a column on thunar
On Libreoffice Writer by going on file>properties>description you can change some properties of the document, such as title, type, add anotations. This is something I use a lot to organize my documents, on my Windows 10 machine I can display the title on Windows Explorer as a column, I was looking for a way to do this on my Xubuntu Linux machine using thunar, but I didn't find a way to do it exactly like on windows, what I have for now is a thunar custom action that runs the script:
#!/bin/bash
title=$(exiftool "$1" | grep Title | grep -o -P '(?<=: ).*(?=)')
zenity --info --title="Title" --text="$title"

But this still not the ideal for me, because I have to go file by file clicking to see the title.
Does anyone have another solution? To add a column that show the title on thunar, or other file explorer that offers this?
